# No appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, syntax-error

I'm trying to use a constructor for a 'Control' class that takes no parameters but when I try to create an instance of it I get an error saying "No appropriate default constructor available"

Here is my header:

```
class Control
{
public:
    Control();

private:
    Layout activeLayout;

    void createLayout();
    void moveWindow(HWND hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight,           std::string windowTitle);
    void mainLoop();
};

#endif
```

My cpp file:

```
 Control::Control()
{
    Detector mainDetector();

    createLayout();
    mainLoop();
}
```

and where I try to call the instructor:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Control mainControl();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention that

```
Detector mainDetector();
```

is a function declaration, not the definition of a variable of type `Control`.
When there are no parameters the syntax is

```
Detector mainDetector;
```

There are cases in which the declaration of a local function is inferred even when it wouldn't seem possible... it's known as the "[the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)" rule of C++.

A simple example is:

```
double pi = 3.141592654;
int int_pi(int(pi));
```

amazingly enough here `int_pi` is declared to be a function!

Comment: Please tell me was that 6502A or 6502B and was it an Acorn or BBC machne

Comment: @EdHeal: sorry... Apple ][ :-)

Comment: I did not know they used the same 8 bit processor. Learn something about the past every day

Comment: Hm, my previous error is gone but now I get a similar "no appropriate default constructor available" error but this time it says 'Layout:' in front of the error.. Does this have to do with the custom 'Layout' struct that I'm using in my Header? I updated the question with my complete Header, really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: @ColdZer0: if the `Control` class contains `Layout` object it must initialize it in the initialization list... the fact that you have a `createLayout` function makes me think you're trying to do that in the constructor body instead. This is not possible... on entering the body of the constructor all members must have been already initialized either in the initialization list or with a default constructor. A bad hacky workaround for this is to write a default constructor for `Layout` that puts it in an invalid state that can be fixed later by the `createLayout` code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 Control mainControl();
```

to

```
 Control mainControl;
```

This should fix the problem